# Facebook Video Player API

Tags: javascript, api, facebook-graph-api, web-applications, video

I'm trying developing a web app that involves taking a user's Facebook videos and allowing them to create user/viewer interactivity. In order to do this I need some sort of Facebook player API similar to the ones YouTube and other video servers offer (that offers eventlisteners, play pause, volume functions). They do not seem to have one though and I've been looking around for a while.

Ideally I would like to contact Facebook and ask if it's possible but I also couldn't find any contact information.

Answer (score 2):

The player is fairly basic, but very easy to find:

It's [linked from every Facebook video page on the frontend of Facebook.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtLzv.png):

And in the [Graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/):

HTTP GET https://graph.facebook.com/2031763147233:

```
{
  "id": "2031763147233", 
  "from": {
    "name": "Facebook", 
    "category": "Product/service", 
    "id": "20531316728"
  }, 
  "name": "Facebook Video Calling", 
  "description": "Bring your conversations to life on Facebook. With face-to-face video 
  "embed_html": "<object width=\"400\" height=\"300\" ><param name=\"allowfullscreen\" value=\"true\" /><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/2031763147233\" /><embed src=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/2031763147233\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"400\" height=\"300\"></embed></object>", 
 //Other fields ommitted
```

And in [FQL](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/video/):
`SELECT vid, title, embed_html FROM video WHERE vid = 3902879808751`
:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "vid": 3902879808751, 
      "title": "Facebook Camera", 
      "embed_html": "<object width=\"400\" height=\"224\" ><param name=\"allowfullscreen\" value=\"true\" /><param name=\"movie\" value=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/3902879808751\" /><embed src=\"http://www.facebook.com/v/3902879808751\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\" allowfullscreen=\"true\" width=\"400\" height=\"224\"></embed></object>"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: I believe you misunderstood my question, but thanks! I already am aware of the above and already have successfully embedded a facebook video. But my true question is whether there's a way to use javascript to manipulate the controls or listen to events. For example, I want a signal to fire when the video ends/plays/pauses.

Comment: you'd have to decompile the player to be sure, but i think no - why not take the source video and load it in your own player?

Comment: Hello Jocelin Lee, Did you find any solution to your need, I'm also looking for an answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Time flew by and now there is an official Facebook Video Player Javascript API.

Here is a link to its docs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player/api